# Views: Multiple Contextual Filters (Taxonomy)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

My view should be filtered by multiple taxonomy terms, e.q. : show me all "events" that are tagged by the terms "show", "age over 40" and "outside".

While I can filter by one taxonomy term just fine, it is not working with multiple terms. 
View Settings:

Relationship: Taxonomy terms on node

Contextual Filters: (term) Taxonomie-Term: Name
Allow multiple values is checked!

What am I doing wrong?

I need to filter by the name, not the ID.

Comment: How you have your filters set up? as expose filters or contextual filters?

Comment: as contextual filters ...

Answer (score 2):

I spent lot of time to figure this out, but finally found a solution:

Instead of `Content: The name of Taxonomy (taxonomy_vocabulary_#)` you need to select `Content: Has taxonomy term ID` *Contextual filter* and enable *Allow multiple values* to able to use multiple values in the form of `1+2+3` (for `OR`) or `1,2,3` (for `AND`).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: it's not possible :( there's a known bug:

https://drupal.org/node/1762770